# Retrieve Data from Project Server Field into Task List

Tags: sharepoint-2013

How to retrieve data from project server custom fields into cutsom list.

Like : There is Project ID fields in pwa, which contains all project ID's. Now the data of this field i want in custom list of project site.

Is there any connection can be made?

Comment: I think this kind of question should be asked in the http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Project Server Interface if you are on 2007+.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms512767(office.14)